# How to choose a heading with user inputs for a Scatterplot with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would have thought that this has been done a lot how ever I cant seem to find an answer.

First off am I asking the right question?

I have a piece of code to make a scatter plot that works but when I try to ad in the functionality of a user input it doesn't work. I think it's to do with the input becoming a string?

What is the difference between these two pieces of code? I am still very new to this so I understand what im asking may not be correct.
'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import string_
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress

datafile = pd.read_csv("/Users/liampyott/Documents/semester 2 2021/411/Assighnment3/Data2/Cliflo/cliflo_normaltemp_consolidated.csv")
print(datafile.head(5))

def Scatterplot(x, y):

    stats=linregress(x,y)
    m=stats.slope
    c=stats.intercept
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.plot(x, m*x + c, color="red")
    plt.show()


x = datafile.Stat_Value
y = datafile.Latitude
Scatterplot(x, y)
```

'''

This works producing a scatter plot. How ever when  I ad input statements it doesnt produce a plot. (in the input fields it would be "Stat_Value" and "Latitude" for x and y

'''

```
xdata = input("Enter field for x axies")
ydata = input("Enter field for y axies")

x = datafile.xdata
y = datafile.ydata
```

'''

Comment: Try switching from dot syntax to bracket syntax in order to specify column names using strings: `x = datafile[xdata]` and `y = datafile[ydata]`

Comment: Thanks Peter this fixed the issue